# Error al conectar socket aplicacion java Andorid(Cliente) con socket aplicacion java PC(Servidor)

Tags: java, android, socket

No me funciona la comunicacion entre los socket de mi aplicacion java andorid (cliente) y mi aplicacion java pc (servidor).

Tengo 2 aplicaciones java, una para movil y otra para ordenador.
Se supone que la aplicacion andorid(cliente) deberia enviarle un mensaje al ordenador (servidor) y que el ordenador lo mostrase por consola.

Cuando lo hago desde otra aplicacion para ordenador si que envia el mensaje, pero poniendo el mismo codigo en la aplicacion para android no lo envia y no se porque. Tengo que decir que cuando me ha funcionado las dos aplicaciones estaban en el mismo ordenador.

El error que me muestra la app de Andorid cuando envio un texto es :

> scoket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Este es el codigo de la aplicacion para Andorid (Cliente) donde tengo definido el socket.

```
public void BontonEnviar(View view) {

    try {

        Socket miSocket = new Socket("192.168.100.190",9999);
        DataOutputStream flujoSalida = new DataOutputStream(miSocket.getOutputStream());

        String mensaje = elementoEntrada.getText().toString();
        flujoSalida.writeUTF(mensaje);

        flujoSalida.close();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        elementoSalida.setText(e1.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Este es el codigo de la aplicacion para PC (Servidor) donde tengo definido el socket:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    try {

        ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(9999);

        Socket miSocket = servidor.accept();

        DataInputStream flujoEntrada = new DataInputStream(miSocket.getInputStream());

        String mensaje = flujoEntrada.readUTF();
        areatexto.append("\n"+mensaje);

        miSocket.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Este es el codigo de la aplicacion para PC (Cliente) donde si me ha funcionado el envio de datos entre aplicaciones:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    try {

        Socket miSocket = new Socket("192.168.100.190",9999);

        DataOutputStream flujoSalida = new DataOutputStream(miSocket.getOutputStream());

        flujoSalida.writeUTF(campo1.getText());

        flujoSalida.close();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu aplicación android debe requerir el permiso `INTERNET` para abrir sockets.

Para ello debes incluirlo en el manifiesto de la app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Lo acabo de poner y ahora el problema que tengo es que cuando pulso el boton que tiene asociado el codigo puesto arriba, se cierra la aplicacion con un error que me dice que la aplicacion ha sido detenedia, vamos que crashea. Si quito el permiso no me crashea pero no tengo permisos.

Comment: Sugiero anadir un manejador de excepción catch general y también inspeccionar que queda en el log del sistema.